# Planetary motion of common center of gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, astrophysics, orbital-motion, planets

I'm trying to solve the following problem but do not quite understand it.

> Assume that a planet with mass $m_{1}$ is orbiting the sun with radius $r_{1}$ (that is $a=r_{1}$ in Keplers 3. law) in a circular motion around the common center of gravity of the planet and the sun.
> Express $r_{1}$ in terms of $m_{1}, m_{2}$ and $R$ which is the distance between the planet and the sun.

Using Keplers 3.law with $a=r_{1}$  I get that

$$\frac{T^{2}}{r_{1}^{3}}=\frac{4\pi^{2}}{G(m_{1}+m_{2})}$$

but where is $R$ in this equation? If $R$ is not equal to $r_{1}$ then the center of gravity must be somewhere outside the center of the sun but I'm not sure how to derive this. Is it then not an elliptical motion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

$$m_{1} \times r_{1} = m_{2} \times r_{2}$$

gives the location of the center of gravity (COG) then

$$r_{1} = \frac{R \times m_{2}}{(m_{1} + m_{2})}$$

If the COG is outside of the physical sun, that does not make it necessarily elliptical motion. The circular motion is around the COG, the elliptical motion is w.r.t. the sun's center.